# javascript minesweeper placed unnecessary "1"

Tags: javascript, minesweeper

i wrote a minesweeper in JavaScript which was working fine for a while, and then randomly on 1 run (i was trying to improve the styling) it gave me this:

[image: stupid 1 in upper right corner]

note the "1" in the upper-right corner as well as 2 missing 1's two and three spaces below it

here is my function for adding numbers to squares:

```
function nextToBombCheck(event) {   
    //reset bomb count
bombCount = 0 ;
    //initialize variable for checking nerby boxes
var nextToBox = 0;
    //asign the box's id as a number
var boxNum = parseInt(event.id);

var checkSide = 0;

for ( var i = 9 ; i <= 11 ; i++ ) {
    nextToBox = boxNum + i;
        //check if its a wrap
    if ( ( nextToBox%10 === 0 && boxNum%10 === 9 ) || ( nextToBox%10 === 9 && boxNum%10 === 0 ) ) {
        continue;
        //check boxes below
    } else if ( bomb.indexOf( nextToBox ) >= 0 ) {
        bombCount++;
    }
}

for ( i = -1 ; i <= 1 ; i++ ) {
    nextToBox = boxNum + i;
        //check if its a wrap (above and below wont work anyway)
    if ( ( nextToBox%10 === 0 && boxNum%10 === 9 ) || ( nextToBox%10 === 9 && boxNum%10 === 0 ) ) {
        continue;
        //check boxes alongside
    } else if ( bomb.indexOf( nextToBox ) >= 0 ) {
        bombCount++;
    }
}

for ( i = -11 ; i <= -9 ; i++ ) {
    nextToBox = boxNum + i;
    if ( ( nextToBox%10 === 0 && boxNum%10 === 9 ) || ( nextToBox%10 === 9 && boxNum%10 === 0 ) ) {
        continue;
        //check boxes above
    } else if ( bomb.indexOf( nextToBox ) >= 0 ) {
        bombCount++;
    }
}
        //set class(colors) based on bombCount
    event.className = classList[ bombCount ];
if ( bombCount !== 0 ) {
        //write number of neighboring bombs
    event.innerHTML = bombCount;
}
}
```

my program works on using a table and each td has an id 0-99

[heres a link if that helps](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/minesweeper.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice game. But you commit the common error of counting the last index. Do you see that your table have size of `11x11 = 121`? But in your program you use

```
var rowAmount = 10;
var columnAmount = 10;

cellAmount = columnAmount * rowAmount;
```

which is wrong. The for loop also explicitly assume there are 11 column:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i <= rowAmount ; i++ ) {
    gameBox += "<tr>";
    for ( var j = 0 ; j <= columnAmount ; j++ ) {
        var idValue = i * 10 + j;
        gameBox += "<td class = 'box' id = '" + idValue + "' onclick = 'process(this);' ></td>";    }
    gameBox += "</tr>";
}
```

but `idValue` is using 10 column. It means that your program will ignore the last column. Change that in all your codes and you will be fine.

Comment: your right i originally wrote it correctly and recently switched from putting a 10 in the loop to using a variable for when i make it possible for users to edit the size and messed that up

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is related to the multiple elements with the same id as you can see in the screen shot from Chrome inspector. As you can notice the last cell of the row and the first cell of the next row have the same id. And this is true for all rows.

[image]

Comment: it looks like your code works for the rows with 10 cells, but you have 11 cells inside each row

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using modulo trickery etc, use X and Y coordinates and have a function to get a cell id from given `X` and `Y`, that is

```
function getCellId(x, y) {
    return 'cell-' + x + '-' + y);
}
```

And name your cell id's `cell-0-0` -> `cell-9-9`

Then the neighboring cells are

```
(x - 1, y - 1)
(x,     y - 1)
(x + 1, y - 1)
(x - 1, y    )
(x + 1, y    )
(x - 1, y + 1)
(x,     y + 1)
(x + 1, y + 1)
```

This problem could have also be avoided, provided that this approach was used.